# Login/ Create user in batch

Tags: batch-file, authentication, interface, admin

I want to make a Admin user interface type of thing! This is my current code:

```
@Echo off
title Administrator login.
color A
echo Type in your Login name!
set/p "nick=>" = <Login.txt
echo Type in your password!
set/p "pass=>" = <Login.txt
echo Welcome !
```

But it won't ask me for my pass/Login name, it just displays the Welcome text!

Comment: The `set /p` code you are using is used to set a variable to the value of the first line of Login.txt. If you want the user to type things in, get rid of `<Login.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
@Echo off
title Administrator login.
color A
echo Type in your Login name!
set/p "nick=Username: "
echo Type in your password!
set/p "pass=password: "
echo Welcome %nick%!
```